# Why liquids aren't uncountable noun?

Tags: articles

Can you make me some **tea**- correct.

Can you make me **a tea**- wrong.

we all know **articles** aren't used before uncountable noun.

Comment: Your second example is not wrong. We can use "tea" (and other beverages) informally as a count noun, where it refers to individual cups of tea, e.g. I can ask a waiter for "two coffee, one hot chocolate, and a/one tea please".

Comment: @BillJ You could also say *I found a tea I really liked at a tea shop in Montreal last year.*

Comment: And articles -- both indefinite and definite - can be used with non-count nouns: "A number of problems remain" / "Kim has a good knowledge of Latin" / "The equipment is faulty" / "The crockery is broken".

Answer (score 2):

Setting aside the **tea** example and just focusing on this "rule"...

Using the article *casts* the noun as a count-noun. A noun not *usually* used as a count-noun can become a count-noun.

> That winter was so cold. It was **a cold** like none we had ever known.
>
> There was something about that New Zealand water. It was **a water** like none we had ever tasted.

There is cold, and there are colds.

There is water, and there are waters.

So, rather than remembering a rule about what you should or shouldn't do, it would be better to understand what the article *does*.

Comment: The indefinite article test is not foolproof. There are a few non-count nouns that can combine with "a", for example "number" ("A number of problems remain") "knowledge" ("Ed has a good knowledge of Greek")and "regard" ("I have a high regard for them"). A count noun by definition is one that can combine with the cardinal numbers _one, two, three_ etc. If it can't it's not a count noun.

Comment: I'm not sure of the value of this cardinal  number test. Can't any noun be made plural? *The philosopher speaks of two knowledges: innate knowledge and acquired knowledge.*  Would you insist that "two knowledges" is ungrammatical, and that we must say "kinds of knowledge"?

Comment: The cardinal number test is the standard test since by definition a count noun is one that can be counted! Plurality is not a test of countability, for example "auspices", "belongings" are both plural nouns but they are non-count. "Knowledge" has no established plural. Your example is certainly non-standard and proves nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Drinks are usually served up in portions of some sort. The drinks in their bulk form are uncountable but the portions of drink are countable.

Sometimes we refer to the portion explicitly "a cup of tea", "a can of coke" but often we just shorten it to "a tea" or "a coke".